# Spring data elasticsearch:throws MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate java.util.Set using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am in process of migrating an application to the latest spring boot version (using gradle spring-boot-dependencies with version 2.5.4).

I have an entity called `Customer` which is annotated with `@Document(indexName = "customer")`; and another entity `Address` which is annotated with `@Document(indexName = "address")`. Customer class has `private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>()`.

Getting the below error, while calling **List hits = elasticsearchTemplate
.search(nativeSearchQuery, Customer.class)** from the repository.

> **org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate java.util.Set using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments**.

It is working if I follow similar MONGO suggestion [Failed to instantiate java.util.Set using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223496/failed-to-instantiate-java-util-set-using-constructor-no-constructor-with-argume) and make the declaration `private HashSet<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>()`. I can't follow this as we have hundreds of entities and their JPA criteria mappings built with JPA Metamodel are failing.

please note that I have already reviewed the below 2  threads and feel it's different:

1. [Indexing problem with Spring Data Elastic migration from 3.x to 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67558754/indexing-problem-with-spring-data-elastic-migration-from-3-x-to-4-x/69232630#69232630)
2. [Spring data elasticsearch: Using @Document annotation on POJO interface class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69172866/spring-data-elasticsearch-using-document-annotation-on-pojo-interface-class-no)

if you are looking for a sample repository: https://gitlab.com/mvallapuneni/spring-es-sample

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: the linked program does not compile. Where is the connection to Elasticsearch configured? Anyway it's not a good idea to use the same entity for a relational database and for a document store like Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Set is an interface not a class.
Interfaces do not have constructors, they are joined to a class that "implements" (has the operating code methods of) the interface.
All method signatures in an interface are abstract , they have no code, only the signature of methods supplied by the implementing class.
e.g. HashSet is a class that implements java.util.Set
See the API documentation at the top of its page for "all known implementing classes"

Your HashSet is **private**  *it must use private methods to call on it e.g. set or get e.t.c.*

To hazard a guess the List must become a Set but List is instantiated and Set is a variable waiting.
Somewhere in the code in private methods this goes like (figuratively)...

```
private Set<Address> addresses = (Set<Address>)(Collection<Address>)elasticsearchTemplate.search(nativeSearchQuery, Customer.class);
```

Note that in that line they are all interfaces but to have an instantiated interface means there is a class attached that implements the interface List , however the class should also be able to use interface Set.
I just presume the List returned is actually in a HashSet and the instantiation is simply reserving space in memory like "C" language, just a helper that is not required to have any class instantiated at that time.
**A HashSet takes a Collection in its constructor and a Collection can be either a Set or a List.**

Comment: your point is right; but it's  the variable declaration in the entity class, do you recommend to use a concrete class as variable than an interface?

Comment: Moreover, the actual issue is when elasticsearchTemplate is trying to map the search results. I mean I don't have a lot of control over it. so, looking for a suggestion on the right way of using the Entity and ElasticsearchTemplate

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch has no problems when a property is defined as `Set<E>`. There must be something different wrong in your setup

Comment: I had a similar issue, but after some time digging the problem was in the index mapping. The field was mapped as an object and contained non, 1, or many records. This approach worked fine in ES Client 7.10 but after moving to 7.12 I started getting same error. Final solution was remapping but setting the class member as `LinkedList` instead of `List` temporary solved my issue